Issue with Importing Circular Image View in Kotlin
I have updated my Gradle file and XMl it's giving error and showing unresolved reference de in gradle and in xml its showing cannot resolve classXML CODEGRADLE CODE
I used the same GitHub Repo for the process but its not working my version of android Studio is
Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-233.14808.21.2331.11842104, built on May 15, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+0--11572160 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 12
Registry:
debugger.new.tool.window.layout=true
ide.experimental.ui=true

Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example

Please [edit] your question and provide all code as text not as a screenshot.

You need to add double quotes:
implementation("de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0")

But as it looks you use a version catalog so you shouldn't do this in the first place. Instead move "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0" to your libs.versions.toml file. For more see this guide: https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs

Aregatto it works

You should mark the answer as accepted as it helps others

You just forget to wrap new dependency notation with "", but since you are using new format you can also add library to your toml file and use new format instead.
Old format
Just wrap the dependency with "" like this and sync your gradle:
implementation("de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0")

New format using libs.versions.toml file
Make sure the dependency reference is declared correctly in your libs.versions.toml like this:
[versions]
#Add this to [versions] block
circleimageview = "3.1.0"

[libraries]
#Add this to [libraries] block
de-hdodenhof-circleimageview = { group = "de.hdodenhof", name = "circleimageview", version = "circleimageview" }

Then sync your gradle files and you can declare dependency like this:
implementation(libs.de.hdodenhof.circleimageview)

